# access denied for Google DLP User

Tags: permissions, cloud, google-cloud-dlp

I am using a service account with Google DLP Role and getting: 403 Not allowed, access denied for permission serviceusage.services.use in a customer-owned account. Google DLP user role appears to have serviceusage.services.use. What else could be preventing a successful call?

Comment: Could you please provide more details with screenshots or command output: what resource, what operation on that resource are you requesting, which user, the user roles, the tool you use?

Comment: Thank you for your response! The issue was related to the fact we were hard coding the Google GCP project id string which was different from the string in the json authentication file. I wish the error were more descriptive, but it was an issue with our code.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was related to the fact we were hardcoding the Google GCP project id string which was different from the string in the json authentication file. I wish the error were more descriptive, but it was an issue with our code.